# Is there any software that can perform real-time physics simulation

Tags: windows

I'm working on a project on how to manoeuvre a back flip with a miniature car, but I want to be sure that my car is the right speed, mass and that the ramp the right slope... Which software do you recommend I use?

Comment: Do you really need real time, i.e. if you manoeuvre takes 0.1 seconds the simulation must be able to complete in the same time?